# OSX vim background getting overridden by terminal background

Tags: vim

I'm using vim 7.3 in Lion OSX.

Whatever theme I have tried to apply retains the terminal's background color, which in my case I've set as `Silver Aerogel` theme.

Curiously, using the theme Zenburn works but breaks after awhile resulting in something that looks like the attached image. In my vimrc, I have this set `set t_Co=256`. My vimrc file: http://dpaste.com/699961/

Help guys?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you comment out line 212: `set t_Co=256`?

Comment: Have you tried seeing if this happens while using a different terminal emulator? e.g. iTerm2?

Comment: That did the trick :D If you re-submit the your comment as an answer, I will acccept!

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem... Then I learned that color schemes designed for gvim or macvim are not necessarily compatible in a 256 terminal.  If it wasn't designed for a 256 color terminal, try the [csapprox](https://github.com/godlygeek/csapprox) plugin. ([csappox description](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390))